# How to join two tables with column having extra characters in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

table 1 : build

```
build_id  |  build_name
----------------------
1         |  build_name_1_signed.bin
2         |  build_2.bin
3         |  build_34534_3_signed.bin
```

table 2 : test

```
test_id  |   test_name     |  build_name
-----------------------------------------
1        |  test1          |  build_name_1_sometext_20245
2        |  test2          |  build_name_1_sometext
3        |  test3          |  build_2-sometext_sometext
4        |  test4          |  build_34534_3_sometext-sometext
```

here I want to join the above two tables using build_name having the same build_name regardless of other characters like **build_name_1** = **build_name_1**_sometext_20245.

Challenge: Not able to use substr() because the lengths are not equal.

I am looking for something like

```
select * from build b, test t where some_function(b.build_name) = some_function(t.build_name)
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to give us some firm rules for when the prefix of each build name needs to end.  It is not clear just from looking at your data how to write a safe query to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the build name has only two possibilities, build suffix may be .bin or signed.bin

Comment: @arundeepchohan No, start name has anything but build suffix has two possibilities like .bin or signed.bin on build table

Comment: Your question is unclear, and I can't write a query just based on what you have said here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mentioned only the build table data having two possible suffixes. Here we can join the column before .bin or signed.bin from build table and check with build name on test table contains the same build name. 
I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: He might be talking about using a JOIN and then a LIKE to compare b.build_name to t.build_name. With some small fixes to b.build_name to only get the 12 OR 7 characters.